# How to run a mango query on a couchdb view?

Tags: python-3.x, couchdb

I use the python package [couchdb](https://couchdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to access a Apache [CouchDB](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/index.html).

My task is to filter documents from the database and be able to select from the filtered database documents with a [mango query](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html).

I have defined a view for my database that filters out irrelevant documents. The map function of the view is a sequence of guards (if statements that return nothing if fulfilled). The last statement emits the document with `key=id` and `value=doc`:

```
function(doc) {
  if(...) {
    return
  }
  emit(doc._id, doc)
}
```

Now I want to use a mango query to select some documents from the view.

But the find method does not exist for views. It only exists for the database object:

- https://couchdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#couchdb.client.Database.find
- https://couchdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#couchdb.client.Database.view

Or does it somehow?

And if not, how can I achieve a filter + a mango find with a couchdb?

Comment: I'd recommend checking [python-cloudant](https://python-cloudant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/view.html#cloudant.view.View) over`couchdb-python` because it gives you more options for interacting with views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot perform a mango query on a view**. You have to choose between these two options.

A view as you implement is a way to *filter and sort* documents in a custom order. Then you can fetch these documents by calling the view and get the exact order you defined.

For example, you can specify a specific range of documents to fetch (with the view) by using [**GET** / **POST** `/{db}/_design/{ddoc}/_view/{view}` endpoint](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html#get--db-_design-ddoc-_view-view) thanks to its parameters (mainly with `startkey`, `endkey`, `descending`, `limit` and `skip`).

But you cannot perform a mango query on a view. **Mango queries can only be done on an entire database**.

In your case, you probably should use mango query and put [indexes](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#post--db-_index) on queryable fields to improve performance.